# Best way to store variable length time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to store >1000 time series data in R, e.g. >1000 daily stock data. Since each stock has a different length and the number of stocks is large, I would like to ask for advice about what kind of data structure I could use to store them in R, for both loading efficiency as well as efficiency in analyzing the data.

Thanks

Comment: I'd think a named `list`, such as `list(AP=1:4, GOOG=5:111)`. The name must be unambiguous and unique.

Comment: Agreed, `list` is best. If you want to do some analysis to each dataset individually then you have the option of `lapply` to apply the same function to each element of the `list`.

Comment: There are several questions here. Do all time series start at the same time? Do they end at the same time? Do they have missing values? Is the period the same (daily price or 1-hour price, for example)? In some circumstances, using sparse matrices may be appropriate. Take a look at the `Matrix` package.

Comment: Another consideration, talischen, would be a database. While it seems odd, this offers several advantages: cross-platform (cross-language) compatibility; consistent persistence; encouragement to use a "long" format for data, which scales better; longitudinal access, meaning that you can add to it very easily; and several other SQL efficiencies. While my advice is still `list` for the immediate work in R, don't dismiss a slightly more formal consideration. (This could be SQLite or something larger like Postgres or SQL Server.)